# Rook OSD after node failure

Tags: kubernetes, ceph, rook-storage

In my kubernetes cluster (v1.14.7)
after a cluster update one node didn't recoverd correctly.
the rook osd from that node didn't get rescheduled ( as it's explained in the documentation)
So im trying to add manually a new OSD.

my `ceph status` return this

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJ4U2.png)

and my `ceph osd tree` return this

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GrsK.png)

I tried link the new osd with the node using `ceph osd crush set osd.0 0.29199 root=default host=gke-dev-dev-110dd9ec-ntww`

but it return:
*Error ENOENT: unable to set item id 0 name 'osd.0' weight 0.29199 at location {host=gke-dev-dev-110dd9ec-ntww,root=default}: does not exist*

Do you got a clue on how to fix this ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I suggest, instead of trying to add a new osd right away, fix/remove the defective one and it should re-create.

Try this:

1 - mark out osd: ceph osd out osd.0
2 - remove from crush map: ceph osd crush remove osd.0
3 - delete caps: ceph auth del osd.0
4 - remove osd: ceph osd rm osd.0
5 - delete the deployment: kubectl delete deployment -n your-cluster-namespace rook-ceph-osd-0
6 - edit out the config section of your osd id and underlying device.
      kubectl edit configmap -n your-cluster-namespace rook-ceph-osd-nodename-config
          delete {"/var/lib/rook":x}
7 - restart the rook-operator pod by deleting the rook-operator pod
8 - verify the health of your cluster: ceph -s; ceph osd tree

Hope this helps!

Comment: hi openJT, thanks for your help. all those step went smooth except the number 6. i couldnt find a configmap related to OSD. so i skipped it, restarted the operator. 

3 jobs started : rook-ceph-osd-prepare-(node_id) with the node_id of my 3 currently running nodes.
but the osd.0 pod didnt restarted. 
ceph crush map tree remain the same

Comment: Did you try to delete the osd pod?

Comment: could you give me more information about the step 6 ?

Comment: really usefull command. the purge job of osd was not do this command:  ceph auth del osd.0

Answer (score 0):

For the rook user: https://rook.io/docs/rook/master/ceph-osd-mgmt.html

A blog to have an explanation(中文读者)：https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/140486398